# can i set MD5 hash key in JAVA or android?

Tags: java, android, hash, md5

I am doing md-5 hashing in both android and c# at the same time.

but I cannot find how to set the MD5 hash key value in java.

this is java code except setting the hash key.

```
     static public String md5(byte[] key, String s) {
    try {

        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(s.getBytes());



        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest(key);

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0; i<messageDigest.length; i++)
            hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]));

        return hexString.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

I want to set hash key value to that code. 
can somebody tell me how can I do that?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean when you say: "I want to set hash key value to that code." As far as I know, there's no key used to calculate an MD5 checksum.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen   i mean i want to set the hash key of MD5

Comment: Just Google for "HMAC MD5 Java", and you'll find a bunch of solutions. For example [this one](http://www.supermind.org/blog/1102/generating-hmac-md5-sha1-sha256-etc-in-java).

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way i can think atm is using the googles class Hashing that has hash method.
http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.java.

The other way you create a method that returns a string and that receives a string

`try{
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            digest.update(password.getBytes());
            String newPass = digest.toString();
            System.out.println("**** " + newPass);
            return newPass;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Author.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return "";`